# Use index on after filter on xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy, xpath-1.0

I have this following xml fragment.

```
<root>
  <site type="main">
    <link>http://stackexchange.com</link>
  </site>
  <site type="qa">
    <link>http://stackoverflow.com</link>
  </site>
  <site type="qa">
    <link>http://superuser.com</link>
  </site>
  <site type="">
    <link>http://data.stackexchange.com</link>
  </site>
</root>
```

I want to select the first site's link of type "qa".  I think `//site[@type="qa"][1]` should do it. But id does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a try to `(//site[@type="qa"])[1]/link/text()`.

Or, alternatively:

```
//site[@type="qa"][position()=1]/link/text()
```

Tested on http://www.xpathtester.com/, results into `http://stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: Why `//site[@type="qa" and position() = 1]/link/text()` would not work?

Comment: You are asking for both conditions to be true simultaneously. You should first search for `qa` attribute and then check the position: `//site[@type="qa"][position()=1]/link/text()`. See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006439/771848).