# Does XPath do short-circuit evaluation of logical expressions?

Tags: xpath, .net-4.0, xmldocument

My question is regarding the order of execution in XPath.

I have an expression such as:

```
//person[@created and customFunction(.)]
```

My problem is that my custom function is quite compute heavy and I only wish for it to run on nodes that have the created attribute set. Will `@created` always be evaluated before `customFunction`? I could cook up a program to test this, but in reality the success of such an experiment is no guarantee, at least not in the long term.

If this is a matter of XPath implementation i am using .NET 4.0.

Comment: I know that this is an old question but I think that my new answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**XPath 1.0 does short-circuit evaluation, in XPath 2.0 and XPath 3.0 it is implementation-dependant**.

According to [XPath 1.0 specs, section 3.4: booleans](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans):

> An ***or* expression** [...] **The right operand is not evaluated if the left operand
>   evaluates to true**.
>
> An ***and* expression** [...] **The right operand is not evaluated if the left operand
>   evaluates to false**.

According to [XPath 2.0 specs, section 3.6: Logical Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-logical-expressions) and [XPath 3.0 specs, section 3.8: Logical Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-logical-expressions):

> **If XPath 1.0 compatibility mode is true** [...] **it is defined that when there is no need to evaluate the second operand in order to determine the result, then no
>   error can occur as a result of evaluating the second operand**.
>
> **If XPath 1.0 compatibility mode is false, the order in which the
>   operands of a logical expression are evaluated is
>   implementation-dependent**. In this case, an or-expression can return
>   true if the first expression evaluated is true, and it can raise an
>   error if evaluation of the first expression raises an error.
>   Similarly, an and-expression can return false if the first expression
>   evaluated is false, and it can raise an error if evaluation of the
>   first expression raises an error. As a result of these rules, a
>   logical expression is not deterministic in the presence of errors, as
>   illustrated in the examples below.

When using XPath 2.0 or XPath 3.0 you can find out whether the current implementation does short-circuit evaluation by evaluating the following example expression:

```
true() or name(1234)
```

The function `name` returns the name of the node parameter, or it raises an error if you pass it for example a number, so:

- If it returns true without rising an error then the implementation does short-circuit evaluation.
- If an error is raised the implementation doesn't do short-circuit evaluation (as it has evaluated the right operand which was not neccessary).

Answer (score 3):

You can also rewrite it as

```
//person[@created][customFunction(.)]
```

This way it only be evaluated for subset filter out by first predicate

Comment: Note that this is not same thing, semantically (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006439/18771). In this case it makes no difference, though.

Comment: This is a practical workaround, and thank you for that! However it does not answer my initial question.