# Get just the first item with DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using this below code to get the elements that are in special HTML element :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($google_html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//span[@class="st"]');    
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $node_value;
}
```

Now, the problem is that, the code gives all of the elements that are in one special class, but i just need to get the First item that has that class name.

So i don't need using `foreach` loops.

How to use that code to get JUST the FIRST item ?

Comment: `$xpath->query('//span[@class="st"][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will make sure you get just the first one in the `DOMNodeList` that is returned

`$xpath->query('//span[@class="st"][1]');`

The following gets the only item in the DOMNodeList

```
$tags = $xpath->query('//span[@class="st"][1]');
$first = $tags->item(0);
$text = $first->textContent;
```

See [XPath: Select first element with a specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006283/xpath-select-first-element-with-a-specific-attribute)

Comment: tnx, but the error :  (( Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in )) + Your code need to be closed with `'` and `)`. any way, not worked !

Comment: @Cab I've updated my answer, you need to get the first item, a [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php), then you need to access whatever property you're looking for

Comment: Tnx alot . Worked perfectly :X