# Xpath for finding element that does not have sibling

Tags: html, dom, xpath, xpath-2.0

So I'm trying to extract the a href locations from the links below but only for the a elements that do NOT have a span sibling. I've managed to figure out the Xpath for finding the ones that DO, but how do I negate this? I've tried using count() and not() but can't seem to get them to be valid or return anything.

```
<div class="member">
    <a href="/test1" class="ahrefclass">shouldntfindme</a>
    <span class="evilspan">evilspan</span>
</div>
<div class="member">
    <a href="/test2" class="ahrefclass">findme</a>
</div>
<div class="member">
    <a href="/test3" class="ahrefclass">shouldntfindme</a>
    <span class="evilspan">evilspan</span>
</div>
<div class="member">
    <a href="/test4" class="ahrefclass">findme</a>
</div>
<div class="member">
    <a href="/test5" class="ahrefclass">shouldntfindme</a>
    <span class="evilspan">evilspan</span>
</div>
```

My Xpath so far is

```
//a[@class="ahrefclass"][../span[@class="evilspan"]]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just negate the condition:

```
//a[@class="ahrefclass"][not(../span[@class="evilspan"])]
```

which is, in this case, equivalent to

```
//a[@class="ahrefclass" and not(../span[@class="evilspan"])]
```

Comment: There is a difference between `[x][y]` and `[x and y]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006439/18771

Comment: ah thanks! I did try using not, unsure why I had no luck, must of been using it in the wrong position or something :-)

Comment: @Tomalak: In this case, they're equivalent.

Comment: In that case yes. It wasn't meant as a correction, but as an addition.

Comment: A little simpler (to my mind) is `//div[not(span/@class='evilspan')]/a[@class='ahrefclass']`