# Retrieving all links within an ordered list using XPath

Tags: java, xpath

How can I retrieve a set of links present as list items in an ordered list using XPath? I need to retrieve all sections from a forum with the following html code:

```
<div id="pagewrapper" class="fixed">
<div id="toplinks" class="toplinks" style="position: relative; top: 145px;">
<div class="above_body" style="height: 210px;">
<div class="body_wrapper">
<div id="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
<div id="pagetitle">
<ol id="forums" class="floatcontainer">
<li id="cat3" class="forumbit_nopost new L1">
<div class="forumhead tcat foruminfo L1 collapse">
<div class="tbody_left">
<div class="tbody_right">
<ol id="c_cat3" class="childforum">
<li id="forum9" class="forumbit_post new L2">
<div class="forumrow table">
<div class="foruminfo td" style="padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px;">
<img id="forum_statusicon_9" class="forumicon" alt="" src="elitex360/statusicon/forum_new-48.png">
<div class="forumdata">
<div class="datacontainer">
<div class="titleline">
<h2 class="forumtitle">
<a href="https://forums.com/forum/index">Forum index</a> <!-- get this link -->
</h2>
</div>
<p class="forumdescription">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<h4 class="nocss_label">Forum Actions:</h4>
<h4 class="nocss_label">Forum Statistics:</h4>
<ul class="forumstats td" style="padding-top: 18px; padding-bottom: 12px;">
<div class="forumlastpost td">
</div>
</li>
<li id="forum22" class="forumbit_post new L2">
<li id="forum40" class="forumbit_post new L2">
</ol>
<div class="tbody_under"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tfoot">
</li>
<li id="cat4" class="forumbit_nopost new L1">
<li id="cat52" class="forumbit_nopost new L1">
<li id="cat5" class="forumbit_nopost new L1">
<li id="cat6" class="forumbit_nopost new L1">
<li id="cat7" class="forumbit_nopost old L1">
</ol>
```

The section links I have to retrieve are marked in the code above (`<!-- get this link -->`). I am now using the following string to retrieve all list items:

```
//div[@id='pagewrapper']/div[3]/ol
```

retrieving all list items. But I don't know how to "enter" each list item and retrieve the link label's contents. In the examples I found, knowledge of the number of list items is necessary [prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006283/xpath-select-first-element-with-a-specific-attribute) to accessing them. That is not the case as the forum may have a different number of list items (the template is for a forum engine, not a forum in particular).

How can I retrieve all links within the list items?

Comment: Consider to include any input sample as a code sample here on stackoverflow instead of linking to an image. As for XPath, if you use `//div[@id='pagewrapper']/div[3]/ol/li//a[@href]`, you will select all link elements inside the `li` list item elements inside that ordered list.

Comment: I'm confused. What "erased line"? Next, `//div[@id='pagewrapper']/div[3]/ol` does not give you list items, it gives you lists. Further, there is not a single link in any of the list items in your sample HTML. Maybe, instead of paraphrasing what you want to select, write down an exact list of HTML elements you want to select.

Comment: @Tomalak In the original post there was an image with the link I wanted to extract crossed out. I've updated the question.

Comment: Okay, and what exactly is the problem? The XPath to get that link is so straightforward that I don't dare to write it down because there must be a catch to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below xpath to get the URL:-

```
//a[contains(.,'Forum index')]/@href
```

If you want all li in ol as I understand from you question then the xpath is as below:-

```
//div[@id='pagewrapper']//li[@id='cat3']//ol//li
```

I think Below is the xpath you are expecting:-

```
   //div[@id='pagewrapper']//div/@href
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I'm trying to get all subforums (sections) present on the index page. The above answer only retrieves one (the one that matches 'Forum index')

Comment: subform means all li in ol?

Comment: subforum = a link to a forum that may have additional subforums or a set of threads. In both cases I need to only extract the link to them (subforums/threads)

Comment: so you need @href where ever it is present in the form .. right?

Comment: yes, but only href's inside div with id=pagewrapper. Other href's may not point to the contents of the forum.

Comment: I have updated my answer . use xpath as :- //div[@id='pagewrapper']//div//@href

Comment: you means all div inside div[@id='pagewrapper'] .. right? or all @href inside div[@id='pagewrapper'] .

Comment: Yes, all links that are inside the div with id pagewrapper

Comment: Updated my answer -> use this xpath -> //div[@id='pagewrapper']//div/@href

Comment: Above xpath return you multiple results. you need to iterate them to get the all the result