# Select the 1st element only - with condition using XML::Twig

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-twig

Having this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->parse( \*DATA );
$twig->set_pretty_print('indented_a');

# 1st search
# this prints OK the all <files> nodes where the <type> == 'release'
$_->print for ( $twig->findnodes( '//type[string()="release"]/..' ) );

# 2nd search    
# try to get first matched only
my $latest = $twig->findnodes( '(//type[string()="release"])[1]/..' );
$latest->print;

__DATA__
<root>
    <files>
        <type>beta</type>
        <ver>3.0</ver>
    </files>
    <files>
        <type>alpha</type>
        <ver>3.0</ver>
    </files>
    <files>
        <type>release</type>
        <ver>2.0</ver>
    </files>
    <files>
        <type>release</type>
        <ver>1.0</ver>
    </files>
</root>
```

The above prints

```
  <files>
    <type>release</type>
    <ver>2.0</ver>
  </files>
  <files>
    <type>release</type>
    <ver>1.0</ver>
  </files>
error in xpath expression (//type[string()="release"])[1]/.. around (//type[string()="release"])[1]/.. at /opt/anyenv/envs/plenv/versions/5.24.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.0/XML/Twig.pm line 3648.
```

The wanted output from the 2nd search

```
    <files>
        <type>release</type>
        <ver>2.0</ver>
    </files>
```

e.g. the first `<files>` node where the `<type> eq 'release'`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1006321/632407) the used XPath expression `(//type[string()="release"])[1]/..'` should work, but seems I again missed something important.

Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) doesn't support the full XPath syntax. The documentation for the `get_xpath` method (the same as `findnodes`) says this

> A subset of the XPATH abbreviated syntax is covered:
>
> ```
> tag
> tag[1] (or any other positive number)
> tag[last()]
> tag[@att] (the attribute exists for the element)
> tag[@att="val"]
> tag[@att=~ /regexp/]
> tag[att1="val1" and att2="val2"]
> tag[att1="val1" or att2="val2"]
> tag[string()="toto"] (returns tag elements which text (as per the text method) 
>                      is toto)
> tag[string()=~/regexp/] (returns tag elements which text (as per the text 
>                         method) matches regexp)
> expressions can start with / (search starts at the document root)
> expressions can start with . (search starts at the current element)
> // can be used to get all descendants instead of just direct children
> * matches any tag
> ```

So subexpressions within parentheses aren't supported, and you may specify only a single predicate

It's also important that, in scalar context, `findnodes` will only ever return a count of the number of nodes found. You must use it in list context to retrieve the nodes themselves, which means that a simpler way to find just the first matching element is to write

```
my ($latest) = $twig->findnodes( '//type[string()="release"]/..' );
```

which works fine

If you really need the full power of XPath, then you can use [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig::XPath) instead. This module uses either [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) or the excellent [`XML::XPathEngine`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPathEngine) to provide the full XPath syntax by overloading `findnodes`. (The other methods `get_xpath` and `find_nodes` continue to use the reduced `XML::Twig` variation.)

`findnodes` in scalar context now returns an [`XML::XPathEngine::NodeSet`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPathEngine::NodeSet) object which has array indexing overloaded. So you can write

```
my $latest = $twig->findnodes( '//type[string()="release"]/..' );
$latest->[0]->print;
```

or just

```
my ($latest) = $twig->findnodes( '//type[string()="release"]/..' );
```

as above.

Finally, I would prefer to see `/root/files[type[string()="release"]]` in preference to the trailing `parent::node()`, but that is purely personal

Comment: YES! Using the `XML::Twig::XPath` and the `my ($latest) = $twig->findnodes( '/root/files[type[string()="release"]]' );` solves my needs. Thank you! ;)

Comment: @cajwine: I hope I made it clear that, if you use only one predicate, like `my ($latest) = $twig->findnodes( '/root/files/type[string()="release"]/..' )`, then the standard `XML::Twig` will work fine

Comment: Yes, just tried both. For using the `'/root/files[type[string()="release"]]'` (from your last statement) I need the XPath. And for the `/root/files/type[string()="release"]/..` is enough the simple `XML::Twig`. Wonderful answer! ;)

Comment: @cajwine: I'm pleased to have helped. Like I said, it seems to be a limit on the predicates, but that's just an educated guess. `mirod` posted an answer as well and he is the author of the module so you may want to ask him some questions

Answer (score 3):

XML::Twig doesn't support all of XPath, but XML::Twig::XPath does.

So `use XML::Twig::XPath;`, then `my $twig = XML::Twig::XPath->parse(...` and voilà... you can now get to fixing the `$latest=...` line, which should be:

```
my $latest = ($twig->findnodes( '(//type[string()="release"])[1]/..' ))[0];
```

(the way you have it $latest is an `XML::XPathEngine::NodeSet`, you need to take the first element of that set).

Comment: This is rather off-topic, but it would be nice if `XML::Twig::XPath` had a way of specifying which helper module to use if they are both installed, in the same way that `Text::CSV` does. Or at least a way of discovering which one had been chosen. It may initially just be a matter of changing `my $XPATH` into `our $XPATH`?

Comment: No question, just a "thank you" for the nice `XML::Twig` package! :)

Comment: @borodin XML::XPathEngine is used if present. XML::XPath is only an option because historically it was  the first one that was used, before I forked the XPath part to create XML::XPathEngine.

Comment: @mirod: I get that. Thanks. But unless you're expecting to deprecate `XML::Path` it would still be nice to be able to get at the information. I've been using `ref $twig->{twig_xp}` so far, which isn't very clean

Answer (score 2):

XML::Twig doesn't support the whole XPath. The expression works correctly in [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML).

You can walk the structure yourself in Perl:

```
my $latest = ($twig->findnodes('//type[string()="release"]'))[0]->parent;
```

Comment: perl-walking - yes - but it says `Can't call method "parent" on an undefined value` if here isn't `release` type (for example just `beta`) - so need test the return value.  Therefore i tried to use the (extended) Xpath. Thank you. :)