# Select position of the fist node that contains value with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>title1</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>title1</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>title2</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>title2</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>title2</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>title2</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>title4</title>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>title5</title>
  </cd>
 </catalog>
```

Is there a way to know the position of the first `<cd>` that contains title2 ?

i have tryed with

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(catalog/cd[contains(., 'title2')])"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(catalog/cd[./title='title2']/preceding-sibling::*)" />
```

but they counts nodes that contains `title2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: Select first element with a specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006283/xpath-select-first-element-with-a-specific-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the expression should be

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//catalog/cd[1]/following-sibling::cd[title='title2'][1]/preceding-sibling::cd)+1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if for-each /catalog/cd and wants to find the first `/title = 'title2'` but starting from the current for-each position, you could use

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(current()[1]/following-sibling::cd[title='title2'][1]/preceding-sibling::cd)+1" />
```

Which is exactly what i need. Thanks @gtosto !