# Get first element having same attributs in xpath query

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

i am on https://www.mister-auto.com
i would like to select the first item of the menu having the attribut `data-selenium='link_front_generic'`

So i tried the following code:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@data-selenium='link_front_generic'])[1]")).click();
```

However, the item is not found

i got the exception:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: Take a look on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006283/xpath-select-first-element-with-a-specific-attribute

Comment: What is the actual exception you get, can you paste it in your question please? From what I can see it's an element that's in a doormat menu so isn't always visible on the page, which may be causing the issue, It depends if it's an element not visible exception or a no such element exception

Comment: I get the exception: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible, as for me it' s always visible isn' t

Comment: @Robert, i think that i tried already that: (.//*[@data-selenium='link_front_generic'])[1] but no success

Comment: Edit the exception message into the question. The `.//` isn't needed here. It's only used when you want to start with an existing element and search down from there. Since you are using `driver.findElement()`, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Element is not visible, because is inside menu wrapper which is not triggered.

You can try with the following code.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Pièces auto']"));
actions.moveToElement(menu);

WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Plaquette de frein']"));
actions.moveToElement(subMenu);
actions.click().build().perform();
```

Comment: hi @Infern0, what i am trying is to use my custom attribut data-selenium, as it doesn' t relate to any DOM change in the future, the other would work, but it relates on the texts, dom etc, which required in the future more maintenance work

Comment: @dtjmsy just change the xpath, if you wish to use custom attributes. I gave you an example solutions, adapt it to your needs.

Comment: i used the code i mentioned in my post: driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@data-selenium='link_front_generic'])[1]")).click(); it works already with other of my other custom attributs except the one that i posted

Comment: @dtjmsy as you described above, the error is 'ElementNotVisibleException' this is due menu wrapper is not triggered a.k.a expanded so the element becomes visible. In this manner i gave you an example how to hover over the menu and click on the element. If you wish to add an custom locator you can change it in the example. its a bad practice to use //* it will go over the whole DOM, write more specific locator ex:(//a[@data-selenium='link_front_generic'])[1] there is plenty of tutorials how to find element by index. If there is something else as an error, please let us know.